# Is it possible to have multiple task pane in a single add-in outlook in office.js

Tags: reactjs, outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin

I have already developed an Outlook add-in featuring a task pane that appears when composing a new message. But now according to client needs I need to have another new taskpane with different functionality in same setup when user read a message/mail. I need to show some information related to to message/mail when another taskpane button is clicked.
So, is it possible to have more than 1 taskpane in a single Outlook add-in react.js setup?